# Single summation for expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following expression

$$\left[(1-4x)(1-3x)(1-2x)\right]\cdot0!(-x)^0+\left[(1-4x)(1-3x)\right]\cdot1!(-x)^2+\left[(1-4x)\right]\cdot2!(-x)^2+3!(-x)^3$$

There is certainly a symmetry here.  The bracketed terms are "descending" as smaller linear factors are missing as we progress left to right.  Also, as we go left to right, we are increasing $i!(-x)^i$.  Is there a way to write this as a single summation?  It is obvious on how to include the $i!(-x)^i$, but the product of linear factors is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the not completely non-standard convention that $\prod_{i=a}^bx_i=1$ if $a>b$, you can write it

$$\sum_{k=0}^3k!(-x)^k\prod_{\ell=0}^{2-k}\Big(1-(4-\ell)x\Big)\;,$$

though I’m not sure how useful it actually is to do so.

Comment: That is what is bothering me... I have been trying to find something cleaner and more compact, but my efforts have been awful.  This is good, but yes, that is a strange thing above with your non-standard convention.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: There really is no standard convention. The one that I used there is actually the one that I’ve seen most often when such inverted limits were allowed at all.

Comment: would it be simpler (more compact) to just remove the last term in the summation and tack it on in front?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: And make it $$3!(-x)^3+\sum_{k=0}^2k!(-x)^k\prod_{\ell=0}^{2-k}\Big(1-(4-\ell)x\Big)\;?$$ You certainly could do that. For me it’s pretty nearly a tossup between explaining the product notation and having the extra term.

Comment: Yeah.  That stinks too i guess but it works  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: You’re welcome!